# Would I be considered overqualified for this internship job posting?

Tags: hiring-process, internship, qualification

I saw a job posting for a company and while I am graduate student pursuing my Masters, I'm hesitant to apply for this internship because one of the requirements for this job is:

- Qualified candidates will be enrolled in a [Bachelors] program and have completed at least 60 hours towards their [Bachelors] degree.

and the title of this job specifically says "Internship" and **NOT** "Undergraduate Student Internship".

While it could be questionably immoral for a graduate student to apply for a job position that requires someone to be enrolling in an undergraduate program (and I could be wrong about this moral dilemma), I'm starting to feel like this job posting isn't meant for someone like me.

I'm not asking for an opinion or a lesson on ethical decisions but rather about the chances of graduate student applying for a position with undergraduate requirements. I could be overthinking this and misunderstanding this qualification listed above as something that could be a ***bare minimum*** qualification. But my mentality is that a graduate student applying for an undergraduate internship would have the same effect as a very experienced worker applying for an entry-level position, someone who is overqualified.

Comment: You're overthinking it - if it's an internship that you want and you feel you'd benefit from, then just state you're a masters student on your resume and apply! Certainly no ethical problem with it.

Comment: Well I just thought I would be stealing an opportunity from an undergraduate student LOL :)

Comment: In that way of thinking, any opportunity you take "steals" it from another, but if you are qualified, the job would help you grow and the employer thinks you are the best fit it is ethical for you to have the job.  They may just say we wanted a less advanced student which is their prerogative.

Comment: "Undergraduate Student Internship" is a subset of "Internship".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're definitely overthinking this and we can't answer this question for you.

If you want to know, there is a simple solution : **apply**

When you'll get an interview, the question will probably come up as to why someone pursuing a Master's degree wants to get into an internship for people in a Bachelors program. Then you could ask them wether they think you are over qualified or not.

Worst case scenario : you'll loose an hour in an interview that will give you a certain amount of insight for the future.

Best case scenario : you get an internship that you actually want.